# unable to save Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am trying to save the below Aura Component but getting error. Code is  -

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="ComponentController">
    <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" value="" default="Mr.Jones" />
    Hello {!v.firstName}!
</aura:component>
```

but getting the below error when I am trying to save this-

```
Field_Integrity_Exception
Failed to save FirstComponent.cmp: 0Ad7F000001ZB2U:3,82: Invalid attribute "value": Source
```

Comment: Value is an attribute for Visualforce, not Lightning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[aura:attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_attribute.htm) dosen't have attribute named `value`. Remove it

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="ComponentController">
    <aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" default="Mr.Jones" />
    Hello {!v.firstName}!
</aura:component>
```